# Как вывести значение из текста

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Парсил сайт с выводом нужного текста.

```
def parse():
    URL = 'https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10500658'
    response = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'col-md-6 server-info')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title': item.find('dl', class_ = 'dl-horizontal')
        })

        for comp in comps:
            print(comp['title'])
```

Вывод:
`<dl class="dl-horizontal"><dt>Rank</dt><dd>#6286</dd><dt>Player count</dt><dd>3/20</dd><dt>Address</dt><dd><span title="185.189.255.206:2956">185.189.255.206<!-- -->:<!-- -->2956</span> <!-- -->(Game Port)<br/> <span title="185.189.255.206:2957">185.189.255.206<!-- -->:<!-- -->2957</span> <!-- -->(Query Port)</dd><dt>Status</dt><dd>online</dd><dt>Distance</dt><dd><span>928 km</span></dd><dt>Country</dt><dd><img alt="Russian Federation" height="11" src="https://cdn.battlemetrics.com/app/assets/ru.addac.gif" title="Russian Federation" width="16"/></dd><dt>Uptime</dt><dd><div>7 Days:<!-- --> <span style="color:hsl(93, 80%, 50%)">93%</span>, 30 Days:<!-- --> <span style="color:hsl(97, 80%, 50%)">97%</span><br/><a href="/servers/valheim/10500658/downtime">Downtime History</a></div></dd></dl>`

Убрал ненужные теги с помощью: `get_text(strip=True)`

Получил:
`Rank#6286Player count4/20Address185.189.255.206:2956(Game Port)185.189.255.206:2957(Query Port)StatusonlineDistance928 kmCountryUptime7 Days:93%, 30 Days:97%Downtime History`

Как мне вывести значение после `Player count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите через `find_all('dd')` все элементы со значимыми данными и, перебирая словарь возвращенных данных по индексам, сохраняйте нужное:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<dl class="dl-horizontal"><dt>Rank</dt><dd>#6286</dd><dt>Player count</dt><dd>3/20</dd><dt>Address</dt><dd><span title="185.189.255.206:2956">185.189.255.206<!-- -->:<!-- -->2956</span> <!-- -->(Game Port)<br/> <span title="185.189.255.206:2957">185.189.255.206<!-- -->:<!-- -->2957</span> <!-- -->(Query Port)</dd><dt>Status</dt><dd>online</dd><dt>Distance</dt><dd><span>928 km</span></dd><dt>Country</dt><dd><img alt="Russian Federation" height="11" src="https://cdn.battlemetrics.com/app/assets/ru.addac.gif" title="Russian Federation" width="16"/></dd><dt>Uptime</dt><dd><div>7 Days:<!-- --> <span style="color:hsl(93, 80%, 50%)">93%</span>, 30 Days:<!-- --> <span style="color:hsl(97, 80%, 50%)">97%</span><br/><a href="/servers/valheim/10500658/downtime">Downtime History</a></div></dd></dl>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
dds = soup.find_all('dd')

rank = dds[0].text
player_count = dds[1].text
# и т.д...
```

```
>>> rank
'#6286'
```

```
>>> player_count
'3/20'
```